# connect: Network is unreachable / no routes

Tags: centos7, wifi, window-managers

I have installed CentOS 7 and added i3wm to it.

Internet is working fine, over wifi, in KDE plasma.

However when in i3 `ifconfig` looks like this:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 44  bytes 4968 (4.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 4968 (4.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4906  bytes 3196764 (3.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3781  bytes 617329 (602.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is not happening when logging into i3.

edit: Following Andreas Rogge suggestion I looked into NetworkManager
output of `service NetworkManager status` is

```
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-07-11 15:17:34 CEST; 20h ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 845 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─845 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.2106] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1499854149.2133] device (wlp2s0): No agents were available for this request.
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.2133] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.2135] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1499854149.2138] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'xxx-wlan'
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.2142] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.2226] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 9A:18:23:6A:34:7E (scanning)
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1499854149.3080] firewall: [0x7f8b88fe7e90,remove:"wlp2s0"]: complete: request failed (UNKNOWN_INTERFACE: 'wlp2s0' is not in any zone)
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.3080] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Jul 12 12:09:09 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1499854149.3283] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> disconnected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find [installation guide](http://sobo.red/CentOS-7-i3wm-Quickstart/)

Notice it has section `Setup network` with [link](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-network-centos-7/)

This link explains how to see that your computer is disconnected

```
nmcli d
```

and then enter gui

```
nmtui
```

as root to setup wifi password and activate for all users.

Network scripts can be found in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-...
```

I guess `nmtui` will add `MODE=Managed`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're lacking NetworkManager. Usually (at least in Gnome) there is a NetworkManager applet and a user instance of something NetworkManager related that pulls the autentication keys for your WiFi from your keyring and establishes the Wifi connection.

I guess i3 doesn't have that component so you need to bring up your Wifi by other means.